# Почему не видятся установленные модули ImportError: No module named south

Tags: python, django, pycharm

В проекте на django используются модули, которые установленны в виртуальном пространстве (virtualenv). Используя pyCharm и настроив виртуальное пространство (проверял его работу при установке новых модулей), запускаю сервер, а он сообщает

```
    (myvenv)root@localhost:/home/Project/mysite# sudo python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named south
```

Проверяю `(myvenv)root@localhost:/home/Project/mysite# pip list`

среди прочего вижу:

```
South (1.0.2)
```

Вот в PyCharm'е:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему тогда показывает `ImportError: No module named south`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` по умолчанию переменные окружения не передаёт, поэтому ваше virtualenv не активировано под root.

Чтобы запустить правильную python команду, можно указать полный путь к ней:

```
$  /home/Project/anyvenv/bin/python ...
```

Если в вашем virtualenv какие-то дополнительные переменные окружения устанавливаются при активации, то можно явно активировать:

```
$ .  /home/Project/anyvenv/bin/activate && python ...
```

Запускать django `manage.py migrate` команду (замена устаревшей syncdb команды) из под root вероятно не стоит.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но мне вас очень трудно понять (у меня мало опыта работы с Debian и django). Мое понимание было бы облегчено примерами конкретно по моему проекту.

Comment: @EmptyMan: ответ не специфичен ни для debian ни для django (к любой Unix системе с sudo и python он применим). Если вы не понимаете слова: "переменные окружения", "запустить команду", "путь", root, то вам стоит вводное руководство по Unix почитать, чтобы с самыми основами познакомиться.

Comment: у меня virtualenv находится здесь `/home/Project/anyvenv/bin/activate` как мне тогда воспользовавшись вашим ответом запустить python комаду: `python manage.py syncdb` ?

Comment: я воспользовался вашим ответом и дописал, получилось так: `# .  /home/Project/anyvenv/bin/activate && python manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 1):

пока решал эту проблему ручным запуском питон-приложения из командной строки, а не через панель PyCharm